# Ubuntu: how to get name of current desktop workspace?

Tags: ubuntu

Is there a way to get the name of the current workspace in Ubuntu?

Comment: What do you mean by workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the [EWMH](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#id2550663) properties `_NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP` and `_NET_DESKTOP_NAMES` are what you're looking for.  With Xlib, you'd use the [XGetWindowProperty](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XGetWindowProperty.html) function.

Comment: do you know if there's a snippet of sample code showing how to get these properties/functions using scripting or some programming language?

Comment: I would be a little surprised if there were scripting language bindings for Xlib, and if there are, it's probably a very thin wrapper around the C functions.  It's been a while since I've done Xlib programming, so you're probably best off just doing a code search for XGetWindowProperty.

Answer (score 0):

You can display the current workspace-number in the top-panel if that helps:

- run "gnome-tweak-tool"
- under Shell-Extensions select "Workspace indicator".